# Unable to show div and set content to it dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am struck on a issue here .
On Page load i want to hide the div panel .
Once the user selects the value i want to show the fetched price inside the div .

This is my program .

I am struck on two issues

**`I am unable to show the div once user selects an Option` .

`I am unable to set the value inside the div` .**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Online Book Store</title>
<script>
function displayResult(selTag)
{
var x=selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].value;
mydiv = document.getElementById("panel");
mydiv.style.visibility = "block"; //to show it
document.getElementById("field_name").innerHTML = x;
}


function hideDiv()
{
    mydiv = document.getElementById("panel");
    mydiv.style.display = "none"; //to hide it  
}
</script>
</head>
<Body Bgcolor = "wheat" onload="hideDiv()">
<center>
<h2> welcome to online shopping</h2>
<form Action = "./onlinebookstore">
select Book
 <select name = "book" onchange="displayResult(this)">
 <option></option>
 <option value=  111>C programming language</option>
 <option value = 112>Java programming language</option>
 <option value = 112>Network analysis</option>
 <option value = 114>Advaced computer Networks</option> 
 <option value =115>Programming analysis</option>
 <option value = 116>Advanced data strctures</option>
 <option value = 117>Advanced java and web technologies</option>
 <option value = 118>Electronic devices</option>
 <option value = 119>Computer Graphics</option>
 <option value = 120>Microprocessors</option>
 <option value = 121>Oracle</option>
 </select>
 <br><br>
  quantity <Input type = "text" name = "Quantity">
 <br><br>
 
  <br><br>
 <div id="panel">
 Price <div id="field_name">TEXT GOES HERE</div>
</div>
 <br><br>
 
 <input type = "submit" name = "s" value = "ADDItem">
 <input type = "submit" name = "s" value = "Removeitem">
 <input type = "submit" name = "s" value = "showitems">
 <input type = "submit" value = "Logout" name = "s">
 </form>
</center>
</Body>
</html>
```

Could anybody please help me

Comment: `bgcolor`? wasn't that deprecated even back in HTML4.01? It's been removed now in HTML5 anyway so best change it :)

Comment: Don't mix "visibility" and "display", they're two separate mechanisms. Use "display" only.

Comment: JSFiddle, please. [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: OT: instead of `select Book <select>...` You should use `<label>`s so: `<label for='sBook'>Select Book</label><select id='sBook' name='book' onchange..>`. Also `onChange()` is annoying to deal with if you cannot use a mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You are mixing and matching visibility and hidden.

Change:

```
mydiv.style.visibility = "block"; // This value is invalid.
```

to

```
mydiv.style.display= "block";
```

if the element is hidden by calling `display:none`, visiblity has no effect on it(even though the visibility property value is correct)

- Call the `hide()` in `window.onload` or end of the body after the element.
- Revisit your option values they have spaces in them (atleast in fiddle).
- You can directly access the select selection value using `.value` i.e selTag.value

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/48WxH/)**

Comment: Thank you very much it worked , can i have the price and its value in same line ??

Comment: @Kiran ofcource by adding `#field_name
{
    display:inline-block;
}`  http://jsfiddle.net/vYvgd/

Comment: Thank you very very much . I am still unable to find the updated jsfiddle related to the price .